# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory trying to open a file: './settings/settings'

Tags: python

I am very new to Python so please forgive the following basic code and problem, but I have been trying to figure out what is causing the error I am getting (I have even looked at similar threads on S.O.) but can't get past my issue.
I'm not sure if I have to redirect or create a directory, and I'm not sure how I'd do so.
Here is my code:

```
 try:
    import json, time, os, re, StringIO
    from PIL import Image
    from urllib import urlencode
    import requests, base58
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except:
    print('ERROR:: missing module(s)')
    exit()


settings = json.loads(open('./settings/settings', 'r').read())
login = open('./settings/login', 'r').read().splitlines()
sessions = []
loginIndex = 0
```

and here is the error I am receiving:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\api\main.py", line 19, in
> <module>
>     settings = json.loads(open('./settings/settings', 'r').read()) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './settings/settings'
```

What is causing the IOError and how to I resolve it?

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\api\settings\settings` exist?

Comment: Yeah the file is there. I was initially able to run it on Win10 PC, but now I'm having troubles running my api on my Win10 VPS

Comment: Try either using the absolute path when opening settings file, or running your program from `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\api` directory.